# Include a formula in SQL Select query

Tags: sql-server, divide-by-zero

Please help me with the below issue.

I need to perform a calculation while fetching data from a Table.  Please help me  on that. Morever I'm getting divsion by zero also.

```
ISNULL(Round(((col4) / (md.col1 + md.col2 + md.col3)), 2), 0)
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trrick. You won't get div/0 error when dividing by null:

```
isnull(Round(((col4)/(NULLIF(md.col1+md.col2+md.col3,0)),2),0)
```

Comment: This is giving result as zero for resulting col and morever im also getting"is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: Yes, you'll get 0 as end result if (md.col1+md.col2+md.col3) == 0. Without NULLIF() you'd get div/0 error. You didn't say what exactly you expect instead of div/0 error, but NULLIF() is certainly one way to handle this error.
As of GROUP BY error - post the entire query, otherwise it's hard to say what's causing the problem.

Comment: This is what a mirror copy of the actual looking query         select ISnull(sum(md.col1+md.col2+md.col3),0) as 'Sum of Columns', ISNULL(sum(md.col4),0) as 'Total ', isnull(Round(((col4)/(md.col1+md.col2+md.col3)),2),0) as colrate from Table2 tbl2 inner join RefTableoftbl2andtbe3 ref on Xref.ID=tbl2.Id inner join table3 on tbl3.Id=ref.ID inner join table1 tbl1 on tbl1.ID=ref.ID and DataEnterdDate='FEB 2013' group by table2colname,table3colname order by table3colname,table2Colname

Comment: It's because colrate is nor enclosed in any aggregate function, neither it's in GROUP BY. It has nothing to do with validity of the expression itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  CASE
        WHEN md.col1+md.col2+md.col3 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE
        ISNULL(Round(((col4)/(md.col1+md.col2+md.col3)),2),0)
        END AS [CALCULATION_RESULT]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about adding:

```
WHERE (md.col1 + md.col2 + md.col3) > 0
```

To your query to filter out the Div0 records?